# AlertManager send Telegram messages

Tags: prometheus, telegram, telegram-bot, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm deploying alertmanager in order to send messages to Telegram with this deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alertmanager
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alertmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      name: alertmanager
      labels:
        app: alertmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alertmanager
        image: prom/alertmanager:latest
        args:
          - "--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml"
          - "--storage.path=/alertmanager"
        ports:
        - name: alertmanager
          containerPort: 9093
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/alertmanager
        - name: alertmanager
          mountPath: /alertmanager
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: alertmanager-config
      - name: alertmanager
        emptyDir: {}
```

And this is de config.yaml:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: alertmanager-config
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  config.yml: |-
    global:
    route:
      receiver: webhook_receiver
      group_by: [alertname, job]
      group_wait: 10s
      repeat_interval: 5m
      routes:
        - receiver: webhook_receiver
          match:
            severity: critical
        - receiver: telegram_receiver
          match:
            severity: critical

    receivers:
    - name: webhook_receiver
      webhook_configs:
        - url: 'https://webhook.site/90befe7e-2a54-4d9a-8a0c-12258dafbb71'
    - name: telegram_receiver
      telegram_configs:
      - api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
        bot_token: 'YYYYYYYYYY:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        chat_id: -YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

The webhook receive correctly the alerts but the Telegram bot doesn't. It is the functionality enabled?
I've followed de Alert Manager offical page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a problem with configuration:both your receivers have the same matchers. In this case first one is selected. To make alertmanager send aletrs to both receivers you need to specify [`continue: true`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#example) option.